# Calculate currency through static base

Tags: logic

I'm working with an API which allows me to get all currencies, but with a base of EUR.

```
EUR: 1,
GBP: 1.15,
USD: 0.86,
```

How could I exchange British pounds into US dollars?
Sorry if this sounds stupid I'm not good in Maths

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your information:

$1 \text{EUR} \iff 1.15 \text{GBP} \iff 0.86 \text{USD}$

if we divide all of the currencies by $1.15$ we get:

$0.87 \text{EUR} \iff 1 \text{GBP} \iff 0.75 \text{USD}$

So, $1$ GBP is $0.75$ USD